# Open HP ALM by code

Tags: alm

Does anyone know if it's possible to launch Internet Explorer, open HP ALM and login with credentials by OTA code or some other way?

I would like to have a program in my computer, that when I run, opens HP ALM logged already.

It's clear for me how to launch Internet Explorer and go to HP ALM site by VBScript with SystemUtil.Run, but it doesn't work to login at ALM, right?!

It's also clear for me how to connect ALM via OTA and work with all kind of data inside ALM, but it doesn't open the ALM in Internet Explorer, as this is just a backend connection.

So, is there another way?

Thanks.
Renan Gaspar.

Answer (score 1):

I get the concern. I have an approach which will work. Why not try with some automation tools like SELENIUM or QTP which can automate this activity in a single click? 
The same can be written using C# if you are aware of it(Since you know vbscript), Selenium supports C#.

Anyways, I am posting a VBS code to automate this job

```
Option Explicit
Dim ie,x
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set x = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ie.Navigate "<YOUR ALM URL>"

ie.Visible=1
wscript.Sleep 7000
x.sendkeys "<USERNAME>"
wscript.Sleep 2000
x.sendkeys "{TAB}"
wscript.Sleep 2000
x.sendkeys "<PASSWORD>"
wscript.Sleep 2000
x.sendkeys "{TAB}"
x.sendkeys "{TAB}"
wscript.Sleep 2000
x.sendkeys "{enter}"
```

This is just the AUTHENTICATION section.
Sleep time is set based on system performance, since everything runs and interacts with the thick client of HP ALM in the system. To choose project, you can use the sendkeys option again according to your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your support, this code actually works, but sendkeys is not really reliable to give it to thousands of users to use. Use QTP or Selenium to that, is like using a cannon to kill a bee and again not feasible to thousands of users. Nowadays with every software using Single Sign On, HP/Micro Focus is still in the past. :(

Comment: SendKeys is of course not reliable. It can throw up anytime causing the whole mechanism to go down. 
But, there is no other way to automate using OPEN SOURCE / Non-3rd Party tools. If anything exists, i would always want to know them and try out. Cheers